# How to send List from controller/View to JS script

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a list in Razor Page which i want to use in java script.I'm using viewdata to send data to view VIewbag is working for some reason in razor page. 
I'm using .net core 2.2

Things i already tried.

View

Things i already tried:

1. var a=@Model.listname
2. var stringArray = @Html.Raw (Json.Serialize(ViewData["Quest"]));` viewdata[Quest] contains list
3. string jsonn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quelist);`
   and then send jsoon to view.
4. using custom class object and create create json object using Newtonsoft.Json and send to view

If you proposing ajex solution explain it a little as i dont know much about it or share a link for explanation

Razor page .cs file Commented the things that didn't

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{           
  ViewData["opt1"] = o1list;
  ViewData["quest"] = quelist;
  //   string jsonn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quelist);
  //   ViewData["Jon"] = jsonn;
  QuestionBank = await _context.QuestionBank
                .Include(q => q.QuestionLevel)
                .Include(q => q.QuestionStyle)
                .Include(q => q.Teacher)
                .Include(q => q.Topic).ToListAsync();
   Answer = await _context.Answer.ToListAsync();
   QSID = await _context.QSID.ToListAsync();
```

View

```
    @{var name = (List<String>)ViewData["Quest"]; }
    <script>
    /*function test() {
    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Jon"]));
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        alert(array[i]);
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
    }
    test();
    */</script>
</head>
<body>
    @{
          Model.run();
          var name = (List<String>)ViewData["Quest"];
          var nam = (List<String>)ViewData["opt1"];
          int j = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
          {
              var a = name[i];
              <p > @a </p>

              <form action="">
                  <input type="radio" name="s" value="">@nam[j]<br>
                  @{j = j + 1; }
                  <input type="radio" name="s" value="">@nam[j]<br>
                  @{j = j + 1; }
                  <input type="radio" name="s" value="">@nam[j]<br>
                  @{j = j + 1; }
                  <input type="radio" name="s" value="">@nam[j]
                  @{j = j + 1; }
              </form>
          }
    }
```

I expect to get a array containing my list or in json format

Comment: You store the data with `ViewData["jon"]` in your controller, but you try to access it with `ViewData[Jon"]` in your view. The key should have the same case for it to work.

Comment: that is not the problem i corrected it same result..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in a project I created:

```
<script>
    var saleTypesById = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TypesById));
</script>
```

Where Model.TypesById is a `Dictionary<long,SaleType>`.

To use from javascript I call:

```
var selectedSaleType = saleTypesById[selectedId];
```

Then I can just call properties on it like `selectedSaleType.Comission`

This code requires `@using Newtonsoft.Json;` directive and a reference to the corresponding nugget package.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the above example but with an extra step:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                window.onload = function () {

                    try {
                        var movsArray = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))';

                        var opt = JSON.parse(movsArray);//Extra step

                        if (opt.length > 0) {
                        //You can use opt as array of objects

                        }

                    } catch (Error) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                };
    </script>
```

or maybe you can use a loop instead of if

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

                    window.onload = function () {

                        try {
                            var movsArray = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))';

                            var opt = JSON.parse(movsArray); //Extra step
                            for(var i = 0;i<opt.length;i++){
                            //you can use opt[i] as object, example opt[i].id
                            }

                        } catch (Error) {
                            console.log("Error");
                        }
                    };
        </script>
```

Where Model is `List<Mov_Tipo>`